# How could I possibly use less variables?

Tags: java, math

I have quickly made a small program that converts Fahrenheit into Celsius and Celsius into Fahrenheit but when I try to use the one variable it doesn't do all of the steps. I can understand why but I cannot figure out how I can prevent it from only doing the last operation because I want it to do all of the operations in order.

As far as im aware if I use the same variable for all of the operations such as the -32, *5 and /9 it will only do the last one because I have used `=` to assign that as the value but I am unsure whether this is the reason or not, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
public class TempConversion{
   //FahrenheitSteps
   private int Fahrenheit;
   private int FahrenheitA;
   private int FahrenheitB;
   private int FahrenheitC;
   //CelciusSteps
   private int Celcius;
   private int CelciusA;
   private int CelciusB;
   private int CelciusC;
   //Constructor
   public TempConversion(){
    Fahrenheit = 0;
    Celcius = 0;
    }
    //Convert Fahrenheit to celcius
    public void FahrenheitToCelcius(int Fahren){
    CelciusA = Fahren - 32;
    CelciusB = CelciusA * 5;
    CelciusC = CelciusB / 9;

    System.out.println(CelciusC + " Is the celcius equivalent");
    } 
    //Convert Celcius to fahrenheit
    public void CelciusToFahrenheit(int Celc){
    FahrenheitA = Celc * 9;
    FahrenheitB = FahrenheitA / 5;
    FahrenheitC = FahrenheitB + 32;

    System.out.println(FahrenheitC + " Is the fahrenheit equivalent");
}

}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using as many variables as you need in a calculation. But storing them as class-level member variables is bad coding practice. Instead, you can convert these to local variables. Do you know how?

Comment: You do not need to do each operation in a separate statement, with separate variables. You can write the whole calculation in one line: `CelciusA = ((Fahren - 32) * 5) / 9;`

Comment: or simply write the entire equation with one variable.. why do you need the intermittent values in this case?  just something like CelciusA = ((Farenheight-32)*5)/9

Comment: Naming things is hard, especially intermediate variables that serve no real purpose.  Take the hint and don't create them!

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'but when i try to use the one variable it doesn't do all of the steps'. What is 'the one variable? Please include the code that is failing and explain the problem.

Comment: I agree with Jesper, you can write the whole thing in one line. But even if you do want to create intermediate variables, the global declaration is unnessasary. You only declare a variabke globally if you need it out of the method. Please explain why you decided to use so many variables to begin with. Try with minimum variables and then post your code if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an example like this https://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-program-to-convert-fahrenheit-to-celsius

And replace `Scanner` with your value.

```
import java.util.*;

class FahrenheitToCelsius {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float temperature;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter temperature in Fahrenheit");
        temperature = in.nextInt();
        temperature = ((temperature - 32)*5)/9;
        System.out.println("temperature in Celsius = " + temperature);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the following three lines:

```
    CelciusA = Fahren - 32;
    CelciusB = CelciusA * 5;
    CelciusC = CelciusB / 9;
```

into

```
Celcius = (Fahren-32) * 5 / 9;
```

The same thing can be done for your celciusToFahrenheit method.
There shouldn't be an issue performing multiple math operations on one line as long as you remember the order of operations.